# What is the best service on Azure to manage huge amounts of data and deliver them ordered to many subscribers

Tags: azure, bigdata, iot, servicebus

**Producer side**

We are trying to ingest a huge amount of data to Azure Cloud. The data are coming from sensors. The rate is about 13 packages per second with a total amount of around 500 KiB/s per sensor. There will be 100'000s of sensors.

**Consumer side**

Then we have some consumer applications that need to retrieve this data (with lowest possible latency) and in the same order, the producer sent the data. Every application needs all of the data of *one* sensor. Per sensor, there will be 5-10 applications/consumers.

[image]

**First approach**

First we tried to solve this with **EventHubs**. That looks most promising in terms of queuing the data and distribute it to consumers. But during load tests, we figured out that there is a hard limit of having the data on *one* partition (what we need because the data need to be ordered at any time). With one partition and the given load, we could handle roughly 4-5 Consumers. With more than 5 consumers, things are getting *laggy* and the consumers could no more hold step with the producer side.

Obviously this is a limitation on the EventHub partition itself and has nothing to do with either the tier (Standard vs. Premium --> no difference) or the scaling units (increasing the scaling units did not made any difference).

The recommendation of Azure for more throughput is simple: Increase the number of partitions per EventHub. But with that we would loose the ordering of the events and the clients would be required to do it for themselves (which is not really achievable). So it seems to us that the EventHubs are not exactly what we need, or we do not use them properly.

**Further thinkings**

We then searched a lot for other services that could give us the required features. We had a look on *ServiceBus* (which we already use for microservice communication). But there, the limits of the amount of data seem to be even more restrictive.

**Question**

What would be the ideal solution for the mentioned problem? Is it possible to be solved with *one* service or do we need to combine several services (like EventHub --> Stream analytivs jobs --> ServiceBus)?

Comment: Ordering in distrubed message system is really hard. Can you clarify how this data will be consumed? All consumers will receive the same data?

Comment: The data will be consumed from different applications and yes, they all need to receive the same data.

Comment: Rolf, did you try out the below approach? You could also try Azure IoT Hub, which provides "ordering" of events. see this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-event-grid-routing-comparison)

Comment: Thank you Anand. We had a chat with Azure support and they suggested a combined solution of Event Hub and Azure Function Apps. I will this here as final solution.
We had a look into IoT Hub, but it seems to be much more expensive than Event Hubs or Service Bus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing with Azure support, we decided to build a combined solution with Event Hubs and Azure Function Apps like this:
[image]

This is currently the best solution for us in terms of costs and complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do as a proof of concept:

-Work with Azure Event Hubs (with multiple partitions)

-Setup Azure Stream analytics and query events in near real time using some windowing function. Then, I would sink data to Azure Service Bus Topic which subscribers would consume later.